# page.evaluate not working but page.exeute_script showing results

Tags: html5-canvas, phantomjs, watir-webdriver

I have been using phantomjs to render canvas element on my page using ThreeJs.
Earlier I was building the page myself, but that did not gave option of adding a background image through system url.
Now after that I started using a `localhost` url, which did not worked when I used `page.evaluate();`
BUT to my surprise when I use Ruby/Watir browser with selenium to do the same operation using `execute_script` method, it works.
I want to know what is it doing differenty that I implement in phantomjs script instead of having watir/selenium etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It could be any number of things. Check that you don't try to access any URLs that you don't have the rights to or disable web-security.

Comment: @Artjom I tried accessing the image url too, it was accessible and visible.